# experiencing issue with route in play 1.2.5

Tags: playframework-1.x

I probably have misconfigured my route file for play-1.2.5 - below is the relevant route file part & the URL being used:

**URL**:

```
GET /application/autoComplete?term=mac
```

**Route:**

```
GET     /autoComplete/{term}     controllers.Application.AutoCompleteTerm
```

I also have the following route defined but its not getting picked up:

```
GET     /autoComplete/     controllers.Application.AutoCompleteTerm
```

The route does not get hit - instead, I get a template not found exception:

```
play.exceptions.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found
```

Any suggestions to help troubleshoot this will be quite welcome.  thanks

Comment: pilot error: the full URL was not being handled by the route - its working now that I'm catching the full URL.  +1 to any who tried to help!  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route:

```
GET     /autoComplete/{term}     controllers.Application.AutoCompleteTerm
```

...is wrong.  It should be like this:

```
GET     /autoComplete/{term}     Application.autoCompleteTerm
```

This would correspond to the following URL:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/autoComplete/mac
```

The corresponding method in Application would look like this:

```
public static void autoCompleteTerm(String term) {
    ...
}
```

The URL:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/autoComplete?term=mac
```

...would need the following route:

```
GET     /autoComplete     Application.autoCompleteTerm
```

...and the same method as above:

```
public static void autoCompleteTerm(String term) {
    ...
}
```